# static variables in data layer, via webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was asked to take over an application, which was running fine under 1-2 users testing it, but once we put it through a larger test, it started crashing. We're seeing random timeouts, along with messages about the code not being able to find certain columns that it expected to be there to bind to, though with just 1-2 users it was working.

The structure of the application is:

```
--------------
| WebSite    |
--------------
| WebService |
--------------
| Database   |
--------------
```

The website does all communication with the database via the webservice. Looking through the webservice code, I saw it was using a class to do the database work, and had this declared as a class level variable:

```
private static SqlConnection cn;
```

This was then being used in all the methods on the page that would need a connection. Being static, this mean there is just one instance for all users correct? I just want to confirm I'm seeing it correctly, as we removed it and are testing it now. Seeing that line to me means that 1 instance of the connection object was being shared amongst all users, which would explain why it was okay for 1-2 users, but the larger the number of users, the more people were queued waiting for it, eventually leading to the random errors. Just want to confirm I'm understanding this correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you disposing the variables like SQl Connection/DataReader etc properly ?

Comment: Add `lock()` over any code handling the commands and when reading data to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Connections are being closed, the using statement is being used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that static variable will be accessed across users. The real root of the problem is the lack of thread safety though, not necessarily the sharing of a connection object.

Comment: +1, and with connection pooling, should be totally unnecessary.

Comment: so being declared static doesn't matter? I thought since it's static there is just 1 instance, thus every time a user wants to connect and get data, they have to share the 1 instance. so if a large amount of data is being brought back the other users will have to wait until the 1st one is done and releases it. Or is that what you mean by Thread Safety? that the multiple users might be changing that same instance as others are using it? as it wasn't just this object he had other variables declared static which were then being used in methods they would change depending on when they were called.

Comment: @ParitoshDass It matters but declaring a variable static does not in and of itself guarantee thread safety.